# Domain over which a polynomial is strictly positive

Tags: polynomials

> $$Q(x) = x^k + a_1x^{k+1}+ ... + a_nx^{k+n}$$ where $k,n$ are positive integers is a polynomial with real coefficients. I have to show that $Q(x)/x^k$ is strictly positive for all real x satisfying $$0<|x|<1/(1+\sum_{i=0}^n |a_i|)$$
> Source: [ISI UGB 2017](https://www.isical.ac.in/%7Eadmission/IsiAdmission/PreviousQuestion/BStat-BMath-UGB-2017.pdf)

Now the polynomial formed after division(which is legal since $x$ is non-zero) is the general $n$ degree polynomial $1+a_1x+...+a_nx^n.$ This approaches $1$ as $x$ approaches $0$. But how can I obtain the right hand part of the inequality? Furthermore, I tried substituting $x=1$ to obtain the right hand denominator but the it doesn't give the sum of the absolute values.

Comment: Please write out your question as it means a) everyone can see it and b) it is searchable on the site. See the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) if you need help with formatting the maths

Comment: I'm sorry. I'll try and edit it.

Comment: I also urge you to write "positive" instead of "+ve" as not everyone knows what the latter means.

Comment: Hope the edit's okay :)

Comment: Mind blowing question

Comment: I found this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x9JJnqlPB5o
 helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We will show that
$$
p(x)=1+a_1x+\ldots+a_nx^n>0\quad\text{for all }x\in X=\left[-\frac{1}{1+\sum|a_i|},\frac{1}{1+\sum|a_i|}\right].
$$
Observations:

1. $|x|\le\frac{1}{1+\sum|a_i|}\le 1$ $\Rightarrow$ $|x|^i\le|x|$.
2. $p(x)=1+\sum a_ix^i\ge 1-\max_{x\in X}|\sum a_ix^i|$.

We can estimate from 1
$$
|\sum a_ix^i|\le\sum|a_i|\underbrace{|x|^i}_{\le |x|}\le|x|\sum|a_i|\le\frac{1}{1+\sum|a_i|}\sum|a_i|<1,\quad\forall x\in X,
$$
then $\max_{x\in X}|\sum a_ix^i|<1$ and from 2 we conclude that $p(x)>1-1=0$ in $X$.